# Is $f(f^{-1}(x))=x \quad \land \quad f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ true for all inverse trigonometric functions?

Tags: analysis, trigonometry, inverse-function

**Based on:**
$f(f^{-1}(x))=x \quad \quad\land\quad \quad f^{-1}(f(x))=x$

**Are all the following definitions true?**

- $\arcsin(\sin x)=x$
- $\sin(\arcsin x) = x$
- $\arccos (\cos x) = x$
- $\cos (\arccos x) = x$
- $\arctan(\tan x) = x$
- $\tan(\arctan x) = x$
- $\text{arccot} (\cot x) = x$
- $\cot (\text{arccot} x)=x$

That's make everything easier if they all were true. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: A serious fault of the high-school treatment of the direct and inverse trigonometric functions (and in many elementary calculus treatments as well) is that they do not give due emphasis to the importance of specifying the domain of definition of each function. In particular, it makes no sense to ask about the “truth” of such statements as those you’ve made without specifying the domain of definition of each function. This is particularly important for the inverse trig functions. As you’ve posed it, your question has no answer.

Comment: These statements are true on the restricted domains of the periodic functions.

Comment: That’s true as far as it goes, @symplectomorphic. But the periodic functions may be restricted in any number of ways… This is yet more obvious when we try to define an inverse of the complex periodic function exp. Once you’ve restricted it to a set small enough for exp to be one-to-one, you’ve got your logarithm. But there are too too many possible such restrictions…

Comment: Oh, agreed entirely @Lubin — I upvoted your comment. Mine was addressed to the OP. By “the” restricted domains, I meant to point OP to the standard ones for these functions on the reals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

To elaborate a bit on the previous answer, inverse trig functions have a limited range, so they’ll give the angle within their allowed quadrants. For example:

$$\arcsin\bigg(\sin \frac{7\pi}{6}\bigg) = -\frac{\pi}{6}$$

This happens since the range of $\arcsin x$ is $\big[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\big]$.

Also, $\tan x$ and $\cot x$ are not defined for all real numbers, unlike their inverse counterparts. You might want to learn the domain and range of the $6$ main trig functions then switch their domains and ranges for their inverses. (Knowing these can help greatly.)

Comment: Thanks. So the conclusion is $f^{-1}(f(x)) = a$ where $a$ is $x$ after the shift ($x$ has to be in $[0; \pi]$ range for $\arccos$,$[\frac{- \pi}{2}; \frac{\pi}{2}] $ for $\arcsin$)? What about $\arctan$ and $\text{arccot}$?

Comment: Yes, you could say something like that! The same applies to those.

Comment: But unlikely to $\arcsin(\sin x)$ and $\arccos(\cos x)$, I don't have to limit $\arctan(\tan x) $ and $\text{arccot}(\cot x) $ domain since they're defined for $x = \mathbb{R}$? Hence $\arctan(\tan x) = x$ where x can be any $\mathbb{R} $ and same about $\text{arccot}$?

Comment: @weno Note that $\tan x$ is defined for any $x$ not of the form $\pi/2+n\pi.$ So it is defined e.g. for $x=100\pi.$ But $\arctan x$ always is in the open interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ So it couldn't work for $x=100\pi$ that $\arctan(\tan x)=x.$

Answer (score 2):

The ones like $\sin(\arcsin(x)=x$ [with the inverse function "inside"] are true, not the others. Try experimenting with large angles for $x.$